# get path attribute value with SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Here is the html in chrome dev-tool:

```
<path class="link" d="M0,130C65,130 65,65 130,65"></path> 
<path class="link" d="M0,130C65,130 65,195 130,195"></path>
```

As you can see from the html which defined two different lines, when I tried to get the value of  tag in javascript like:

```
console.log($('path')[0].attributes.d.value); 
console.log($('path')[1].attributes.d.value);
```

I got this:

> M0,730C0,730 0,730 0,730
>
> M0,730C0,730 0,730 0,730

the same value, why? and i also tried other attributes like d.nodeValue the same result,How two different lines got same values?

When I tried it in `$(document).ready(function () {})`, It will be the same value, if I put the console.log in a "on-click" function will be the correct result, may be the initialization problem.

Comment: What about `$('path').eq(1).attr('d')`?

Comment: I just test in a snippet and it works fine for me. Maybe there is other svg or path in your page

Comment: Still the "M0,730C0,730 0,730 0,730"

Comment: There must be another path there, this value doesn't correspond to neither the paths you linked. Besides that, if you want a jQuery solution, please remove the D3 tag and add a jQuery tag.

Comment: You can't rely on the position within a jQuery selector.

Comment: Here's a JSBin showing what I presume to be the correct behavior as well... https://jsbin.com/kemesazeca/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation would be:

```
var element = $("path[class='text']");

    console.log(element[0].attributes[1].nodeValue);
    console.log(element[1].attributes[1].nodeValue);
```